# Error: Program type already present: com.rom4ek.arcnavigationview.R

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors, build.gradle

Successfully compiled app eventually got stuck when I an changed icon color. Hence I closed the emulator. After that when I rerun the emulator , I always receive below build gradle error. And a previous version of the app is available in the emulator but not the new changes.

Any idea on how to fix this issue ?

```
build failed    11 s 936 ms
Run build   10 s 560 ms
```

> Program type already present: com.rom4ek.arcnavigationview.R
>
> org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform$DexConversionWorkAction
>   org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process C:\Users\Desktop\Project\testapp\app\build\intermediates\javac\debug\classes 
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\Desktop\Project\testapp\app\build\intermediates\javac\debug\classes 
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
>   com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete 
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.rom4ek.arcnavigationview.R

Build > Clean Project > Rebuild Project solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Build > Clean Project > Rebuild Project** solved the issue.